# Unity 3D block faces

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello i'm quite new to unity and wanted to make a simple 3D game. Now i have my script which generate cubes and i was wondering because it's a lot of blocks how to make a script which check if one side of a block is touching another so that face won't be rendered hope you can help me. Here is my script for generating blocks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Block_render : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        int suma=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
                {
                    GameObject chonk = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                    chonk.transform.position = new Vector3(0 + j, 0 + i, 0 + k);
                    chonk.AddComponent<MeshFaces>();
                    suma ++;
                    print(suma);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you have some way to check if a block exists at a location. Just check the six adjacent locations.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: Then, perhaps, write a system that stores what block exists at every location so you can quickly check to see if a block exists at a location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're concerned about rendering performance, it's probably too early and you should use the [profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) and the overdraw view in the editor.

Check out this stuff on [Occlusion Culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) and Backface Culling (which is on by default) to improve performance in the way you're describing.

If you want to determine which faces of cubes are touching, you first have to determine if they are touching at all, which means you could use `OnCollisionEnter` or `OnTriggerEnter` depending on your collider settings. Then you should be able to use the `Collision` or `Collider` object (respectively) passed in to determine the face.